# Pausing a process?

Tags: python, process, signals

Is there a way to pause a process (running from an executable) so that it stops the cpu load while it's paused, and waits till it's unpaused to go on with its work? Possibly in python, or in some way accessible by python.

Comment: do you mean thread or running system process ?

Comment: I would be inclined to lower process priority rather than "pausing" it. That way other processes will go first

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By using psutil ( https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil ):

```
>>> import psutil
>>> somepid = 1023
>>> p = psutil.Process(somepid)
>>> p.suspend()
>>> p.resume()
```

Answer (score 7):

you are thinking of [SIGTSTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGTSTP) -- the same signal that happens when you push `CTRL-Z`. This suspends the process until it gets [SIGCONT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGCONT).

of course, some programs can just catch and ignore this signal, so it depends on the executable. however, if you can suspend and resume it manually, you can do it from a python program, too. use `os.kill()`

Comment: and how do I unsuspend it so that it continues work from where it was before?

Comment: SIGSTOP can't be blocked and would be slightly more accurate in this context, not coming from a tty. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSTOP

Answer (score 2):

I just implemented this with signals in python something like this:

```
def mysignalhandler(sig, frame):
  print "Got " + str(sig)
  if sig == signal.SIGUSR1:
    do_something()

signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, mysignalhandler)

signal.pause()
```

This will pause at the last line and call `do_something()` when it receives the signal USR1, for example through a

```
kill -USR1 <pid>
```

command.

This will only work in UNIX though.

Answer (score -2):

There is a (almost) **native** way of doing this in Python, and it's quite simple :

```
import time
time.sleep(5)
```

In this snippet, `5` is the number of **seconds** you want to pause your program.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question; which is about pausing *another* process.