# Python: Function to stop and start a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

I am searching for function to stop a subprocess in python3 and if you use that function again it should start at the point it was stopped.

So basicly I want to put the process on a hold till it may go on.

It'd be wonderful if someone could help me ;)

Comment: Is this using threads?

Comment: no, it is using Flask, so you can send the stop via another route

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804287/pausing-a-process

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find that :), I will try it :)