# How to suspend and resume processes from a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x

First I tried to pause the [youtube-dl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youtube-dl) process and resume it when needed [using Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631220/206574). It did not work out. Now I am trying to suspend and resume processes using Python. I have taken guideline from [Pausing a process?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4230243). Now my script looks like:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import psutil
import time

x = [p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'youtube-dl' in p.info['name']]
mypid = x[0]['pid']
print(mypid)

p = psutil.Process(mypid)
p.suspend()
time.sleep(10)
p.resume()
```

When I run the above script, the terminal running `youtube-dl` shows:

```
zsh: suspended  youtube-dl
```

And then:

```
% jobs

[1]  + suspended  youtube-dl
```

I have to go to the terminal and type the following command to continue the process:

```
% fg %1

[1]  + continued  youtube-dl
```

How can I resume processes from a script instead of going to the terminal and typing a command?

Just for the sake of being thorough, If I run `tail -f ~/.xsession-errors`, and replace

```
x = [p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'youtube-dl' in p.info['name']]
```

with

```
x = [p.info for p in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']) if 'tail' in p.info['name']]
```

Then it pauses and resumes the `tail` command as intended. However, it does not work with `youtube-dl` command as mentioned above.

Comment: as I know `fg` can use `pid` instead of `%1` and then you could try to use `fg` in python.

Comment: do you ger any error when you try to `resume()` it?

Comment: it does not show anything. Probably the process resume in the background. I see nothing. One thing, if I use `pid` with `fg` then how will it know on which terminal the command will come in foreground? Is there any command like "resume process id 1234 and bring it in the foreground of x terminal"?

Comment: I don't know - I used `fg` only manually in terminal. And programs should be already assigned to terminal - when you run `ps aux` then you see column `TTY` which shows on which terminal it works.

Comment: @furas I took your guideline. we can get the terminal name using `ptsname=$(ps aux | grep 38648 | awk '{ print $7 }')` and continue that process in that terminal using `kill -CONT 39905 > /dev${ptsname}`. However, I am not still sure how the complete python script will look like.